# Can two verbs be used one after another?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I noticed a sentence today in an article:

> The index counts start from 1 instead of 0.

I'm not sure if this is a grammatically correct sentence and just want to confirm. As I remember, you can't use two verbs one after another. Here *count* and *start* are all verbs. So, is it correct? If not, what the correct way to express the same meaning?

BTW, the original article is talking about a programming structure *array* and how the indexing of it works.

Comment: I think the author intended *counts* to be a noun here.

Comment: Actually, "counts" is used as a noun here.  "Index" is a noun-adjunct, that is, a noun acting as an adjective to describe what sort of counts are being talked about.

Comment: Can I say "the index counts starting from..." and use "count" as a verb?

Comment: @OgrishMan: You can. And it means essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Hellion Could you post your answer as an answer rather than a comment?  I'm certain you have the right answer, and would like to upvote it as an answer, but... you left a comment instead.

Comment: Please provide more context, preferably link to the article in question. The word "counts" may be a name of a variable, or a plural noun, or it may be an grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written, "index counts" is a noun phrase consisting of the noun *counts*, which is the same as *counters* (a thing used to indicate your position within an array), modified by the noun adjunct *index*.  The noun adjunct is basically a noun being used as an adjective to describe what kind of counts they are:  They are counts for indexes.  So this really is not an example of using 2 verbs in a row.